# Unpacking firefox via maven for Selenium

Tags: maven, firefox, selenium

**Problem** How can I ensure correct browser versions at test execution time for selenium to run against?

Given that selenium requires specific browser version and I don't want to manage installing and updating versions on win (lin would be easier via puppet) I need a way to deploy the right browser version during my build.

Is this what other folks are doing?

- bundle firefox, chrome browser versions as archive files
- deploy these to my maven repository (nexus)
- at build time use dependency plugin unpack goal to extract browser archive to target//
- at test execution time, feed in location to browser executable and use that with selenium driver

Or is there a plugin that already handles this for me and am I re-inventing the wheel.

Thanks for the help.

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ceased to be an issue as my team decided to use chrome not firefox.  So, here's the whole process for handling chrome driver and unpacking chrome.  you can easily adjust it for firefox.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38984738/9950